# Why doesn't the Politics site have the same Graphics support and markup support as other sites?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

I recently answered a question where I would ordinarily have used a table.  The given markup facilities do not allow this.  I suggest that tables are an important and useful way of discussing politics and should be allowed.  This would almost certainly be a simple configuration adjustment for technical support.

Comment: This is now [status-complete], due to recent upgrades

Answer (score 4):

This requires a bit more than  "a simple configuration adjustment for technical support". The requests to implement Markdown tables in the version of Markdown used on Stack Exchange sites go back 6-8 years.

- [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables)
- [Can we add Markdown support for tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/can-we-add-markdown-support-for-tables)

A glimpse of hope was [offered by a Stack Exchange employee recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304223/tables-are-almost-by-definition-imperative-on-stack-exchange-why-are-they-still#comment988877_304223):

> The update to CommonMark (and the inclusion of tables) for Q&A is currently planned for 2018, but that's really all we have at the moment. "Do this in 2018."

The best thing we have currently is the 3rd party tool [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) by Senseful (a Stack Exchange user). It turns tab-delimited text into a table that can be pasted here and "formatted as code", with the following result.

```
+-------+--------------------------+
| Year  |          Status          |
+-------+--------------------------+
| 2008  | No Markdown tables       |
| 2018  | Still no Markdown tables |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: the site is deliberately excluding the Mark down tool from https://markdown-here.com that is available as an extension for Chrome, at least.  It's excellent and presumably safe.  Perhaps worth another respectful tap on the techies' door?  

The Senseful product is so Internet 1.0. 

I'm not sure it makes commercial or technical sense to avoid useful browser extensions.